# Facebook Send Dialog fails to send links to Facebook itself -- why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use [Facebook Send Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) in a WinForms frame with a browser control and direct URI (you can repro just by clicking the links below). It works fine with link=http://www.foo.com, sending the message properly if you enter a message and click "Send":

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=179873125388138&link=http://www.foo.com&redirect_uri=http://jonnewman.com/&display=popup&to=100002395463043

However, this fails with link=http://www.facebook.com or any path under it. Clicking "Send" just gets you "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.":

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=179873125388138&link=http://www.facebook.com&redirect_uri=http://jonnewman.com/&display=popup&to=100002395463043

The aim is to write a script to make it easier to send messages asking all users in a particular group to a page (prepopulating the recipient list). Since Facebook has restricted groups larger than 500 members, our organization has to move to a Facebook Page, and I want the Send Dialog to link the new Facebook Page. Why won't this work? Is there a workaround? Are there other criteria for what links Send Dialog will and won't send?

Also, is there a way I can determine whether the send occurred or not, for example an event to catch? Whether you send or cancel, the Navigated event is still redirect_uri/#_=_.

Once I have Send Dialog working, I will add Show-FBSendDialog to [Facebook PowerShell Module](http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com), which already has numerous capabilities to automate Facebook from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

ran some tests and it seems it is blocking any fb domain http://on.fb.me/91S2P8, sometimes this is temporary otherwise need to rethink...

Answer (score 0):

I see your second link isn't working... but if you add your company page id or name to link it should work. following link works for me:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=179873125388138&link=http://www.facebook.com/Intel&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjonnewman.com%2F&display=popup&to=100002395463043

hope this helps

Comment: Imran, it's very odd -- the link you provided works, but this link fails:
[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=179873125388138&link=https://www.facebook.com/pages/Jconnect-Seattle/321877637741&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjonnewman.com%2F&display=popup&to=100002395463043](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=179873125388138&link=https://www.facebook.com/pages/Jconnect-Seattle/321877637741&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjonnewman.com%2F&display=popup&to=100002395463043)  
I wish I knew what it is about the Link= link which makes this work or not work.

Comment: One possible reason could be your company page does not have any username...
for e.g. https://www.facebook.com/Intel
or https://www.facebook.com/Microsoft
If we try your url
https://www.facebook.com/Jconnect-Seattle
we get error page
Did you tried creating username for your page?
You can read more about it here https://www.facebook.com/blog.php?post=90316352130

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. I also had same problem. No post helped me. Solving error for 2 days.

There were posibility of two mistakes(that was done by me).

1. Link Parameter given in url should be working. I have linked to api namespace but not given SSL url. So it was giving problem. You can given your web site address.
2. And redirect_uri parameter should be working. Try to give redirect_uri to same page most probably.